# Android TextView link without underline?

Tags: android

I use a TextView with links by this:

```
TextView tv ... 
tv.setText( Html.fromHtml(somehtml))
```

It is ok to control the link color by setting attribute android:textColorLink, but can I remove the underline of it?

Comment: Why do you put the <u> tag there if you actually don't want it to be underlined?
Also, it's not really a link, is it? There's no <a> tag and you're also not using Linkify. So it's just a url printed as text, isn't it?
Therefore, I don't fully understand the above mentioned problem yet, but have you tried to use and add/override styles/css in the html you pass along?

Answer (score 3):

OK now with html anchor tag, to avoid the underline now use the property STYLE="text-decoration:none"

< a STYLE="text-decoration:none" HREF=\"link.html\">it has no underline < /a >

**this must work with a WebView but in a TextView I was using Android 1.5, 1.6 and thats not possible. =(**

Comment: so bad, I don't want to use webView everywhere, but seems no other way now. anyway thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the html < u > tag, that indicates an underline text !

Comment: The text that I will put into the TextView will be a html with <a> tag, and I want to make the link text in another color, so I use Html.fromHtml, but seems no way to remove the underline

Answer (score 0):

```
Spanned android.text.Html.fromHtml(String source, ImageGetter imageGetter, TagHandler tagHandler)
```

The important part is the TagHandler. You have to implement one and then you can hopefully modify it.

Another solution:
[handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)