# how to create textview link without underscore in android

Tags: android, textcolor, text-decorations

i came into this wired situation, my code is as follow

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
ll.addView(tv);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a STYLE=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"" 
        + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(elem.getChildText("newsLink")) + "\">" 
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(elem.getChildText("Title")) + "</a>"));
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

but the `style="text-decoration:none"` and `tv.setTextColor(color.black)`both not working, the link is still in blue with underscore, any hints on why they're not working? Thanks!

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115956/android-textview-link-without-underline

Comment: I tried the second one, but doesn't work, i'm wondering why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try this. such as

```
String content = "your <a href='http://some.url'>html</a> content";
```

Here is a concise way to remove underlines from hyperlinks:

```
Spannable s = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(content);
for (URLSpan u: s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class)) {
    s.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan() {
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
            tp.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }, s.getSpanStart(u), s.getSpanEnd(u), 0);
}
tv.setText(s);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! and do not have to create another class! by the way, any thoughts on why setTextColor(Color.BALCK) not work?

Comment: please click accept symbol for earn 10 reputations, please

Comment: I solved this, setTextColor() can not change the link color, need to use setLinkTextColor()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spannable` and `URLSpan` here to remove hyperlink underline from your code

First of all make your anchor tag text into `Spannable`

```
Spannable spannedText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(
            Html.fromHtml(webLinkText));
```

Create new class `URLSpanNoUnderline` and extend it with `URLSpan` and override `updateDrawState` method. in that method you can set `setUnderlineText` to `false`

then use this method you can remove your link

```
public static Spannable removeUnderlines(Spannable p_Text) {  
       URLSpan[] spans = p_Text.getSpans(0, p_Text.length(), URLSpan.class);  
       for (URLSpan span : spans) {  
            int start = p_Text.getSpanStart(span);  
            int end = p_Text.getSpanEnd(span);  
            p_Text.removeSpan(span);  
            span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());  
            p_Text.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);  
       }  
       return p_Text;  
  }
```

For more information you can visit this [link](https://prativas.wordpress.com/category/android/textview-hyperlink-change-color-and-remove-underline/)