# Android: Start activity via link in TextView

Tags: android, android-widget, linkify

I have a TextView which I fill with HTML and linkify it then. Some of the links in HTML are in special format and meant to be links to other activities in my project, not normal URL links. Is it possible to intercept clicks on such links in TextView and do custom action in case the link is in special format?

Thanks.

Comment: If you could provide some code, we'd be in a better position to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A question about how to manage link click has already been post and should answer your question.
Here is the link : 
[handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)