# Hypertext to an activity

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I hypertext a textView to an activity not to a url ? I have a textView "Sign up" which I want to take the user to an activity .

Please help me

Comment: What you want to do? clear your question first.

Comment: if you want : set the TextView **underlined**

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, there is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320561/android-start-activity-via-link-in-textview

Comment: Can you set the textview to clickable and then use a click event in your code to load the next activity?

Comment: yes this is what I mean , I want to click on a textView to open a new activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Spanned signUpString=Html.fromHtml("<u><font color=\"#ffbb00\">signUp</font></u>");

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(signUpString);

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) 
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, Second.class));
        }
    };

    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0 , 6, Spannable.SPAN_INTERMEDIATE);

    TextView signUpTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTVid);
    signUpTextView.setText(ss);
    signUpTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I hope this helps you...

Comment: It gives me error :( Please any help

Comment: what and where you getting the error in this code??