# Open a link in a webview instead of default browser

Tags: android, webview

I have this piece of code:

```
    TextView noteView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    noteView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    noteView.setText(Html.fromHtml(noteView.getText().toString()));
```

I need to open links in a webview, not in a browser... is this possible?? how can I do??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, it's pretty simple task with WebView, you need to declare a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) object and override the `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` method, there you can filter urls or give some customized functionality.

In your case, to stay on the WebView, you would need to return false on that method.

Check out [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Regards

*EDITED:*

It seems your question is how to handle the click event on the TextView's url. As [it's suggested on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app) you can filter the `ACTION_VIEW` intent on your WebView containing Activity. If you need [more guidance about intent-filters, check this out](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

Comment: Thanks but well, this doesn't work... I have no WebView at the start...when I click on a link I would to show up the web view instead of the browser ^^ is it possibile?

Comment: @Erenwoid, Now I get your question, you want to handle the Intent when is dispatched on the TextView url's click. Well see my edited answer.

Comment: But stillit forces you to display the app chooser, for the user will be able to browse via an external browser

Answer (score 7):

additional, you can do this.

```
    package com.TextHtml;

    import android.app.Activity;  
    import android.content.Context;  
    import android.os.Bundle;  
    import android.text.Html;  
    import android.text.Spannable;  
    import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;  
    import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;  
    import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;  
    import android.text.style.URLSpan;  
    import android.view.View;  
    import android.widget.TextView;  
    import android.widget.Toast;  
    public class TextHtml extends Activity {

        private TextView  tv;  
        static Context ctx=null;  
        @Override  
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  
            ctx=this;  
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);   
            String htmlLinkText = "<a href="/" mce_href="/""http://www.google.com/"><u>hello google </u></a>";     
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlLinkText));  
            tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());     
            CharSequence text = tv.getText();     
            if(text instanceof Spannable){     
                int end = text.length();     
                Spannable sp = (Spannable)tv.getText();     
                URLSpan[] urls=sp.getSpans(0, end, URLSpan.class);      
                SpannableStringBuilder style=new SpannableStringBuilder(text);     
                style.clearSpans();//should clear old spans     
                for(URLSpan url : urls){     
                    CustomerTextClick click = new CustomerTextClick(url.getURL());     
                    style.setSpan(click,sp.getSpanStart(url),sp.getSpanEnd(url),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);     
                }     
                tv.setText(style);     
            }  
        }  

        private static class CustomerTextClick extends ClickableSpan{     

            private String mUrl;     
            MyURLSpan(String url) {     
                mUrl =url;     
            }     
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View widget) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "hello google!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }     
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Best answer if you don't want to add intent filters to the web view activity.

Comment: Best answer ever!