# How can we open TextView's links into Webview

Tags: android

How can I open `TextView`'s links into `WebView` when I click on links of `TextView`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636283/open-a-link-in-a-webview-instead-of-default-browser

Answer (score 30):

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://google.com\">google.com</a>");
textView.setText(spanned);
```

**EDIT**: That's not an ideal way to handle clicks on a link, but I don't know any other way.

Your main activity contains a `TextView` with a link. The link URL has a custom scheme.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView link = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.link);
        link.setText(
            Html.fromHtml("<a href='myscheme://www.google.com'>link</a>"));
        link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

When this link is clicked Android starts an `Activity` with `ACTION_VIEW` using the link URL. Let's assume you have a `WebViewActivity` which handles URIs with this custom scheme. It gets the passed URI and replaces its scheme with `http`.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        if( savedInstanceState == null ) {
            String url =
                getIntent().getDataString().replace("myscheme://", "http://");
            // do something with this URL.
        }
    }
}
```

To handle custom URI schemes `WebViewActivity` must have an intent filter in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks Pixie, But it will open in default browser not in WebView. :(

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. In this case you can create an URL with your own schema and register it with an intent filter in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Thank You Again, But can you explain it little bit more.

Comment: @Michael, what if I fetch the text from the web and I can't modify the scheme?

Comment: @Ozuf What do you mean you can't? You can always create a link with a custom scheme and add another link to it as a query parameter. Then when handling this URI you can extract the inner link and open it in the `WebView`.

Comment: @Michael: I fetch the text from external source (web), and the url is handed down to me. Please, how can I modify the scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me. I just used the onTouchEvent code from LinkMovementMethod. You set the link in textView as Michael mentioned above or you can set it in strings.xml. I use this library for opening links https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/CustomTabsHelper.

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new MovementMethod() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(TextView widget, Spannable text) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(TextView widget, Spannable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(TextView widget, Spannable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyOther(TextView view, Spannable text, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTakeFocus(TextView widget, Spannable text, int direction) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTrackballEvent(TextView widget, Spannable text, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Borrowed code for detecting and selecting link from
         * {@link LinkMovementMethod#onTouchEvent(TextView, Spannable, MotionEvent)}
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                    action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
                y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

                x += widget.getScrollX();
                y += widget.getScrollY();

                Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
                int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

                ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

                if (link.length != 0) {
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        // do whatever else you want here on link being clicked
                        Selection.removeSelection(buffer);

                    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                                buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                                buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                    }

                    return true;
                } else {
                    Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(TextView widget, Spannable text, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canSelectArbitrarily() {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you copy a Kotlin solution of [nastylion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58956236/2914140), you can use it like:

```
textView.handleUrlClicks { url ->
    Timber.d("click on found span: $url")
    // Call WebView here.
}
```

Also you can see [an article](https://medium.com/@Saketme/a-better-way-to-handle-links-in-textview-27bb70b2d31c) with its `LinkMovementMethod` and `linkify`, but it's too difficult (contains different masks and popup menus).

Answer (score 0):

set the property **android:autolink** to your textview layout

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="your text"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

Comment: This opens links in browser. Answer is how to open links in WebView

Comment: Just a little problem. After applying autoLink, color turned to Green and applying different color not working. Hows that ?

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

```
hotel_website=(TextView)viewflipper.findViewById(R.id.tv_website);
hotel_website.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    String url = "http://" +hotel_website.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
   }
});
```

and in XML

```
<TextView
  android:clickable="true"
</TextView>
```