# Open desired link in webview

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to open link which is in text view in the form of text:type ="autolink"
and it contains some URL but when a user tap on it, opens browser instead of webview activity

For Example

```
{

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="www.facebook.com"
        android:id="@+id/iimage" />

}
```

so please tell if a user clicks on this link it opens in webView in WebView activity. How to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply by:

```
    iimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity, youractivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", your_url );
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Inside onCreate of your youractivity

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");



webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Except www.google.com no other links is not working like facebook,youtube

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set a Spannable to your textview and set the click listener on that Spannable.

Here you have an example i took from some answer: [Android: ClickableSpan in clickable TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183645/android-clickablespan-in-clickable-textview)

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview01);      
Spannable span = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable("test link span");   
span.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        Log.d("main", "link clicked");
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "link clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } }, 5, 9, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// All the rest will have the same spannable.
ClickableSpan cs = new ClickableSpan() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        Log.d("main", "textview clicked");
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "textview clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } };

// set the "test " spannable.
span.setSpan(cs, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// set the " span" spannable
span.setSpan(cs, 6, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText(span);

tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [How can we open TextView's links into Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255249/how-can-we-open-textviews-links-into-webview)

But actually all you need is webView.loadUrl("www.facebook.com")

Comment: no bro I am trying to open text view links in other activity with webview not just by loading loadUrl();

Comment: Well, ok. And what a problem to pass String to other activity in intent extras, in activity extract it and put to webView?