# Open URL in WebView instead of default Browser

Tags: android, url, webview, textview, intentfilter

I am creating simple `Webview` application with some links on `textview` and open those links in `webview` instead of default browser. My `textview` contains various different URLS and i am trying to open each link in webview of my app.

Here code:

```
tv.setText("www.google.com  www.facebook.com  www.yahoo.com");
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());;
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()));
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS);


WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
       {
           // Override page so it's load on my view only
           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
           {
            // This line we let me load only pages inside Firstdroid Webpage
            if ( url.contains("www") == true )
               // Load new URL Don't override URL Link
               return false;

            // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
            return true;
           }
       };

wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);      

    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    wv.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);

    // Load URL
    wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Already tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255249/how-can-we-open-textviews-links-into-webview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636283/open-a-link-in-a-webview-instead-of-default-browser) examples but couldn't solve my issue with multiple links in the `textview`. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

**Edit**
My `Textview` contains strings like:

```
hello xyz some more statements... xyz.com/abc/
hello xyz some more statements... xyz.com/abc/
hello xyz some more statements... xyz.com/abc/
hello xyz some more statements... xyz.com/abc/
```

Like this it has many strings and multiple URL's

Comment: What's it doing or not doing that you'd like to change?

Comment: I want to open url click from textview to open in webview

Comment: Do you want all the links in different web views ?

Comment: No in same WebView. whichever user clicks link from textview that link should open in one webview

Comment: Post some sample content from a TextView so that we can see how the multiple links are separated. And how do you want these links displayed? One after another or in multiple simultaneous WebViews or ???

Comment: is there really a need in your application that forces you to use single textview for different urls??? @HimaniAgarwal

Comment: @scottt Pleaser check my edit this is how my textview is and contains multiple n number of links in it.

Comment: @AndroidGeek Yes it is. I have only one text view with many strings and in between some URL's

Comment: I posted an answer that basically states that Linkify is apparently not understanding your links since they don't include a scheme.

Comment: can you use WebView instead of TextView? if you use webview so you can be able to load URLs into that webview.

Answer (score 30):

The following problems need to be solved:

1. Linkify the TextView
2. Find a way to listen to a click on a link in the TextView
3. Get the url of the clicked link and load it in the WebView
4. Optional: make the TextView clickable without losing the ability to select text
5. Optional: handle formatted text in the TextView (different text sizes and styles)

**#1 Linkify the TextView**

That's the easiest problem and you already solved that one. I suggest to do it this way:

```
String text = "These are some sample links:\nwww.google.com\nwww.facebook.com\nwww.yahoo.com";
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString( Html.fromHtml(text) );
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

I'm using a Spannable here to solve problem #2.

**#2 + #3 Listen to clicks on links and open them in the WebView**

To find out when a link is clicked and retrieve the URL we have to open, we replace all URLSpans in the TextView by our LinkSpan (that's why we need a Spannable):

```
URLSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), URLSpan.class);
for (URLSpan urlSpan : spans) {
    LinkSpan linkSpan = new LinkSpan(urlSpan.getURL());
    int spanStart = spannable.getSpanStart(urlSpan);
    int spanEnd = spannable.getSpanEnd(urlSpan);
    spannable.setSpan(linkSpan, spanStart, spanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannable.removeSpan(urlSpan);
}
```

Our LinkSpan simply grabs the clicked url and opens it in the WebView:

```
private class LinkSpan extends URLSpan {
    private LinkSpan(String url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String url = getURL();
        if (mWebView != null && url != null) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously we have to keep a reference to the WebView in an instance variable to make this work. To make this answer as short as possible I chose to define LinkSpan as an inner class but I'd recommend to define it as a top-level. Register a listener or pass the WebView as a parameter to the constructor instead.

Without setting the MovementMethod to LinkMovementMethod the TextView won't open links at all:

```
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tv.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Last but not least let's make sure the WebView doesn't start the browser but loads the page within the app:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // we handle the url ourselves if it's a network url (http / https) 
        return ! URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url);
    }
});
```

**#4 Clickable and selectable TextView + #5 formatted Text**

If the MovementMethod is set to LinkMovementMethod you can click links but you can't select text any more (you need ArrowKeyMovementMethod for that). To solve this I created an custom MovementMethod class that inherits from ArrowKeyMovementMethod and adds the ability to click links. On top of that it is able to deal with formatted text. So if you decide to use different font sizes and styles in the TextView the following MovementMethod will have it covered (works with EditTexts as well):

```
/**
 * ArrowKeyMovementMethod does support selection of text but not the clicking of links.
 * LinkMovementMethod does support clicking of links but not the selection of text.
 * This class adds the link clicking to the ArrowKeyMovementMethod.
 * We basically take the LinkMovementMethod onTouchEvent code and remove the line
 *      Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
 * which deselects all text when no link was found.
 */
public class EnhancedLinkMovementMethod extends ArrowKeyMovementMethod {

    private static EnhancedLinkMovementMethod sInstance;

    private static Rect sLineBounds = new Rect();

    public static MovementMethod getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new EnhancedLinkMovementMethod();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            int index = getCharIndexAt(widget, event);
            if (index != -1) {
                ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(index, index, ClickableSpan.class);
                if (link.length != 0) {
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        link[0].onClick(widget);
                    }
                    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Selection.setSelection(buffer, buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]), buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            /*else {
                Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
            }*/

        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }

    private int getCharIndexAt(TextView textView, MotionEvent event) {
        // get coordinates
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        x -= textView.getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= textView.getTotalPaddingTop();
        x += textView.getScrollX();
        y += textView.getScrollY();

        /*
         * Fail-fast check of the line bound.
         * If we're not within the line bound no character was touched
         */
        Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        synchronized (sLineBounds) {
            layout.getLineBounds(line, sLineBounds);
            if (! sLineBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // retrieve line text
        Spanned text = (Spanned) textView.getText();
        int lineStart = layout.getLineStart(line);
        int lineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(line);
        int lineLength = lineEnd - lineStart;
        if (lineLength == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        Spanned lineText = (Spanned) text.subSequence(lineStart, lineEnd);

        // compute leading margin and subtract it from the x coordinate
        int margin = 0;
        LeadingMarginSpan[] marginSpans = lineText.getSpans(0, lineLength, LeadingMarginSpan.class);
        if (marginSpans != null) {
            for (LeadingMarginSpan span : marginSpans) {
                margin += span.getLeadingMargin(true);
            }
        }
        x -= margin;

        // retrieve text widths
        float[] widths = new float[lineLength];
        TextPaint paint = textView.getPaint();
        paint.getTextWidths(lineText, 0, lineLength, widths);

        // scale text widths by relative font size (absolute size / default size)
        final float defaultSize = textView.getTextSize();
        float scaleFactor = 1f;
        AbsoluteSizeSpan[] absSpans = lineText.getSpans(0, lineLength, AbsoluteSizeSpan.class);
        if (absSpans != null) {
            for (AbsoluteSizeSpan span : absSpans) {
                int spanStart = lineText.getSpanStart(span);
                int spanEnd = lineText.getSpanEnd(span);
                scaleFactor = span.getSize() / defaultSize;
                int start = Math.max(lineStart, spanStart);
                int end = Math.min(lineEnd, spanEnd);
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    widths[i] *= scaleFactor;
                }
            }
        }

        // find index of touched character
        float startChar = 0;
        float endChar = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
            startChar = endChar;
            endChar += widths[i];
            if (endChar >= x) {
                // which "end" is closer to x, the start or the end of the character?
                int index = lineStart + (x - startChar < endChar - x ? i : i + 1);
                //Logger.e(Logger.LOG_TAG, "Found character: " + (text.length()>index ? text.charAt(index) : ""));
                return index;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Complete Activity code**

Here's the complete sample Activity code that I used. It should do exactly what you want. It's using my EnhandedMovementMethod but you can use a simple LinkMovementMethod (with the drawbacks mentioned before).

```
public class LinkTestActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        String text = "These are some sample links:\nwww.google.com\nwww.facebook.com\nwww.yahoo.com";

        // Linkify the TextView
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString( Html.fromHtml(text) );
        Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

        // Replace each URLSpan by a LinkSpan
        URLSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for (URLSpan urlSpan : spans) {
            LinkSpan linkSpan = new LinkSpan(urlSpan.getURL());
            int spanStart = spannable.getSpanStart(urlSpan);
            int spanEnd = spannable.getSpanEnd(urlSpan);
            spannable.setSpan(linkSpan, spanStart, spanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spannable.removeSpan(urlSpan);
        }

        // Make sure the TextView supports clicking on Links
        tv.setMovementMethod(EnhancedLinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tv.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        // Make sure we handle clicked links ourselves
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // we handle the url ourselves if it's a network url (http / https) 
                return ! URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url);
            }
        });

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);      
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    private class LinkSpan extends URLSpan {
        private LinkSpan(String url) {
            super(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = getURL();
            if (mWebView != null && url != null) {
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EnhancedLinkMovementMethod doesn't seem to allow selections properly

Comment: @kenyee but it does ;-). That code works for thousands of my users and if you think otherwise you'd have to show some evidence.

Comment: So I'm an idiot...I didn't set  android:textIsSelectable="true"...lol.  sorry :-)

Comment: Excellent answer. Well written as well as explained :)

Answer (score 3):

The WebViewClient is set by call `setWebViewClient()` method on you WebView refrence.

Firstly set all properties for webview then call `loadURL(String url)` method, It will open sublinks to same webview instead of open into browser.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);
WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya but issue is that there are many different URL's in `TextView` and when user click any of link desired URL has to be open in `WebView`. So I am seeking that how to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Webview` Application will receive Link when some link is clicked. User manually have to select your application. specifying host "like www.apptechinc.com" will launch this application when any link from that site is clicked.

```
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="www.apptecxinc.com" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In Activity you can receive this link as :

```
    String action = getIntent().getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            webview.loadUrl(urlsetup(uri.getPath())); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that Linkify is looking for a scheme to detect links. Without `http://`, it isn't detecting your links as web URLs. The solution would be to make sure your links include the scheme or define a custom regular expression pattern to match. It's not clear from your sample TextView data what the pattern should be. [Here's  a page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) that shows how to use the custom pattern once you work out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of @Emanuel Moecklin 's answer is to subclass `URLSpan` and create your own `URLSpan` which has `onClick` overrided.

Inspired by his answer, instead of following fully his steps, I sticked to using `Linkify`. However, for some other reasons, I created my own `Linkify` class, with almost the same code as original `Linkify`.

And then, inside `applyLink()` in Linkify, I replaced

```
URLSpan span = new URLSpan(url);
```

with

```
InAppURLSpan span = new InAppURLSpan(url);
```

Where the code for `InAppURLSpan` is:

```
public static class InAppURLSpan extends URLSpan {

    public InAppURLSpan(String url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        String url = getURL();
        Log.i("TNC_URL", url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(widget.getContext(), SingleWebViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_URL, url);
        widget.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And it worked like a charm~

Answer (score -1):

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);      

wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    // Links clicked will be shown on the webview
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }   
}); 
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I'd rather make 3 textviews / buttons for your links and set its onClickListener to do a webview.loadurl(url)