# After clicking link in textview, how to open that link in webview instead of default browser?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-webview

I have a text view. In that I have text like this "You may visit this: http://www.google.com". After clicking this link it should open it in a webview instead of default browser. My code is:

//MainActivity.java

```
link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
link.setText("You may visit here : http://www.google.com");
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

//Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.xpointers.xpmediaapp.mediaapp.WebViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I tried using this link: [handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app) but failed to understand and what should I write in WebviewActivity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962621/open-url-in-webview-instead-of-default-browser

Comment: @Golu I got this but is there any need to use click listener for text view also?

Comment: see Emanuel Moecklin answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following problems need to be solved:

Linkify the TextView
Find a way to listen to a click on a link in the TextView
Get the url of the clicked link and load it in the WebView
Optional: make the TextView clickable without losing the ability to select text
Optional: handle formatted text in the TextView (different text sizes and styles)

## 1 Linkify the TextView

```
String text = "These are some sample links:\nwww.google.com\nwww.facebook.com\nwww.yahoo.com";
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString( Html.fromHtml(text) );
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

## 2 + #3 Listen to clicks on links and open them in the WebView

```
URLSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), URLSpan.class);
for (URLSpan urlSpan : spans) {
    LinkSpan linkSpan = new LinkSpan(urlSpan.getURL());
    int spanStart = spannable.getSpanStart(urlSpan);
    int spanEnd = spannable.getSpanEnd(urlSpan);
    spannable.setSpan(linkSpan, spanStart, spanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannable.removeSpan(urlSpan);
}
```

For opening in new activity:

```
 private class LinkSpan extends URLSpan {
        private LinkSpan(String url) {
            super(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = getURL();
            if (url != null) {


                startActivity(new Intent(LinkTestActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class).putExtra("url",url));

            }
        }
    }
```

And loding the url in webview.

for more see below link :-

[Open URL in WebView instead of default Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962621/open-url-in-webview-instead-of-default-browser)

Comment: When I try to settext with the above resulting string like textview.setText(text); it shows me the plain text, without even provision to click it. How else do I need to setText?

Comment: @King, use `setText(Html.fromHtml(s))`, where s should containg a text like "see here: &lt;a href="http://example.com/">example&lt;/a>"

Comment: @Duggu onClick is never called.. When i click on link, it opens in default browser.

Comment: For this solution to work, we need to disable autolinking (android:autoLink view tag shouldn't be set to "web") and also set movement method on the textview programatically: textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Answer (score 1):

As of the link you posted, you should declare in Manifest file that your certain activity can open links. When such link is clicked, your activity is opened, therefore you should set launch mode to singleTop. Then you can receive new intents and display them in your webview.
onNewIntent:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

This example is about implementing search, so you can skip to the "singleTop" part:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Place this code after `link.setText(--url--);`

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.account_title))
                .getText().toString();
            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
);
```

Create a webview in your relevant xml file, like this:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/wv"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

That's it...
Let me know if you are still getting some issue.

Comment: bro i want to open it in new activity.

Comment: @Ak10147 No issue, you can use same script for new activity, Just create a new JAVA class and put java code in onCreate() method then create a new .XML file and place above xml code in your parent layout.