# Handle android TextView's link click

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

So i have a textView and sometimes my textView contains links, currently when i click in this link an intent with a list of downloaded browsers opens. now what i want is, i wanna open this link inside the current app, say in a WebView. how can i do this?

we do have multiple articles/questions  on same topic but i have no idea what this articles/questions are really about.

like this one https://gist.github.com/ksoichiro/3394338 gave me an **ClassCastException** 
`android.text.style.URLSpan cannot be cast to pb.myPackage.LinkUtils$SensibleUrlSpan`

or this one [handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)

is there's any straight simple way to achieve this? please let me know.

Comment: refer this answer
[Open URL in WebView instead of default Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962621/open-url-in-webview-instead-of-default-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Chrome Custom Tabs, this is faster than a webview in loading webpages and is pretty simple to customize.

First include the Library:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.1.1'
}
```

Then in your `Activity` when you call the method to open a browser add these lines of java:

```
String url = ¨https://google.com/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent intent = builder.build();
intent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Refer to it's docs for more customization at:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs