# How can I replace a word in a string to make it clickable

Tags: android

How can I replace a word in a string  and make it hyperlink..
For example : 
              This is a car.
I want to replace it with,
               This is  a [car](http://car).

I am using

```
 str.replaceAll("car", "<a href=\"\">$1</a>" );
```

Is it correct regularexpression to make it hyperlink or not?
Thank you..

Comment: How are you displaying the string?

Comment: I am displaying it in a textview . @Drakosha

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app

Comment: You're not sure? Well ... what happens when you try it?

Comment: @Brian Roach The textview is blank..

Comment: Have you considered using linkify? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Linkify will do what you want. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html.