# ListView: TextView with LinkMovementMethod makes list item unclickable?

Tags: android

What I want to do: A list with messages like this:

> <UserName> and here is the mnessage the user writes, that will wrap nicely to the next line. exactly like this.

What I have:

**ListView** R.layout.list_item:

```
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="(Message Text)" />
```

Adapter that inflates the above layout and does:

```
SpannableStringBuilder f = new SpannableStringBuilder(check.getContent());
f.append(username);
f.setSpan(new InternalURLSpan(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}), f.length() - username.length(), f.length(),
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

f.append(" " + message);

messageTextView.setText(f);
messageTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
meesageTextView.setFocusable(false);
```

The InternalURLSpan class

```
public class InternalURLSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    OnClickListener mListener;

    public InternalURLSpan(OnClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        mListener.onClick(widget);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
}
```

In the activity I have in `onCreate(...)`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(ProgramChecksActivity.this);
```

and the implementation of the above

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The problem:

Clicking on the item, does not show the toast. Only clicking on the username does show the toast.

I am guessing, that `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` makes the TextView clickable. So the items themselves do never get clicked anymore.

How can I make the items clickable again? Having the same functionality as I want.

Comment: Not sure just try making TextView of ListView row focusable=false in the xml android try.

Comment: Tried that, but it does not work :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app/16644228#16644228

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are THREE show-stoppers in this situation. The root reason is that when you call `setMovementMethod` or `setKeyListener`, `TextView` "fixes" it's settings:

```
setFocusable(true);
setClickable(true);
setLongClickable(true);
```

The first problem is that when a View is clickable - it always consumes `ACTION_UP` event (it returns true in `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`).
To fix that you should return true in that method only if the user actually clicks the URL.

But the `LinkMovementMethod` doesn't tell us, if the user actually clicked a link. It returns "true" in it's `onTouch` if the user clicks the link, but also in many other cases.

So, actually I did a trick here:

```
public class TextViewFixTouchConsume extends TextView {

    boolean dontConsumeNonUrlClicks = true;
    boolean linkHit;

    public TextViewFixTouchConsume(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewFixTouchConsume(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewFixTouchConsume(
        Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        linkHit = false;
        boolean res = super.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (dontConsumeNonUrlClicks)
            return linkHit;
        return res;

    }

    public void setTextViewHTML(String html)
    {
        CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
        SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = 
            new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
        setText(strBuilder);
    }

    public static class LocalLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod{
        static LocalLinkMovementMethod sInstance;


        public static LocalLinkMovementMethod getInstance() {
            if (sInstance == null)
                sInstance = new LocalLinkMovementMethod();

            return sInstance;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, 
            Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                    action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
                y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

                x += widget.getScrollX();
                y += widget.getScrollY();

                Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
                int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

                ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(
                    off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

                if (link.length != 0) {
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        link[0].onClick(widget);
                    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                                buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                                buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                    }

                    if (widget instanceof TextViewFixTouchConsume){
                        ((TextViewFixTouchConsume) widget).linkHit = true;
                    }
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
                    Touch.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return Touch.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
        }
    }
}
```

You should call somewhere

```
textView.setMovementMethod(
    TextViewFixTouchConsume.LocalLinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
);
```

to set this MovementMethod for the textView.

This MovementMethod raises a flag in `TextViewFixTouchConsume` if user actually hits link.
(only in `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN` events) and `TextViewFixTouchConsume.onTouchEvent` returns true only if user actually hit link.

But that's not all!!!!
The third problem is that `ListView` (`AbsListView`) calls it's `performClick` method (that calls `onItemClick` event handler) ONLY if `ListView`'s item view has no focusables.
So, you need to override

```
@Override
public boolean hasFocusable() {
    return false;
}
```

in a view that you add to `ListView`. 
(in my case that is a layout that contains textView)

or you can use `setOnClickLIstener` for that view.
The trick is not very good, but it works.

Comment: For anyone who needs it, here's the corresponding Mono code: http://pastebin.com/8SvMRaN9

Comment: This solution invoke another problem —— the longItemClick invokes after just click the list item but not press and held.

Answer (score 48):

babay's answer is very nice. But if you don't want to subclass TextView and don't care about LinkMovementMethod features other than clicking on links you could use this approach (this is basically copying LinkMovementMethod's onTouch functionality into TextView's OnTouchListener):

```
        myTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                boolean ret = false;
                CharSequence text = ((TextView) v).getText();
                Spannable stext = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
                TextView widget = (TextView) v;
                int action = event.getAction();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                        action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();

                    x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
                    y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

                    x += widget.getScrollX();
                    y += widget.getScrollY();

                    Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
                    int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                    int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

                    ClickableSpan[] link = stext.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

                    if (link.length != 0) {
                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            link[0].onClick(widget);
                        }
                        ret = true;
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            }
        });
```

Just assign this listener to your TextView in your list adapter getView() method.

Comment: This fix will make the click on the area outside the ClickableSpan being consider as clicking the ClickableSpan. I think you should check the area is inside bound first.

Comment: @DennisK, This gives a warning: 'onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected 
'.

Answer (score 5):

Here is quick fix that makes `ListView` items and `TextView` `UrlSpans` clickable:

```
   private class YourListadapter extends BaseAdapter {

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           ((ViewGroup)convertView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

           return convertView
       }

    }
```

Comment: This worked in my case too, except I was able to set it straight in the XML: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in that LinkMovementMethod indicates that are going to manage the touch event, independiently the touch is in a Spannable or in normal text.

This should work.

```
public class HtmlTextView extends TextView {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (getMovementMethod() == null ) {
            boolean result = super.onTouchEvent(event); 
            return result;
        }

        MovementMethod m = getMovementMethod();     
        setMovementMethod(null);

        boolean mt = m.onTouchEvent(this, (Spannable) getText(), event);
        if (mt && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            mt = m.onTouchEvent(this, (Spannable) getText(), event);
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
        }

        boolean st = super.onTouchEvent(event);

        setMovementMethod(m);
        setFocusable(false);

        return mt || st;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get double onClick happening on my ClickableSpans

Answer (score 2):

This is happened because when we press on list item it sends the press event to all its children, so the child's **setPressed** calls rather than the list item. Hence for clicking the list item, you have to set the child's **setPressed** to false. For this, you have to make custom **TextView** class and override the desired method. Here is the sample code

public class DontPressWithParentTextView extends TextView {

```
public DontPressWithParentTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    // If the parent is pressed, do not set to pressed.
    if (pressed && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
        return;
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
}
```

}

Comment: @PatrickBoos this doesn't work in your case since the the textview holds the all space of the row, if there are more than one item in the row(list item) than try it.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution use the list item layout with two different text:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.me.test.DontPressWithParentTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="(Message Text)" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="(Message Text)" />
```

and the adapter code as:

```
DontPressWithParentTextView text1 =  (DontPressWithParentTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_user);

                TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_message);
                text2.setText(message);

                SpannableStringBuilder f = new SpannableStringBuilder();
                CharSequence username = names1[position];
                f.append(username );
                f.setSpan(new InternalURLSpan(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }), f.length() - username.length(), f.length(),
                        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                f.append(" ");

                text1.setText(f);
                text1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                text1.setFocusable(false);
```

This will work.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()`? You can provide the same in adapter by `messageTextView.setOnClickListener()`.

Another method - set second clickable span for message - and provide actions there. If you don't want second part looks like a linke create

```
public class InternalClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    OnClickListener mListener;

    public InternalClickableSpan(OnClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        mListener.onClick(widget);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        ds.setColor(Color.WHITE);// Here you can provide any color - take it from resources or from theme.
    }
}
```

Comment: Because setOnItemClickListener is the nicer way to go. The Activity should handle what happens if an item is clicked. Since the adapter can be used in different places and a click could be handled in different ways.

Comment: A second clickable span would work. But I would prefer if there is a way to get it work through setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: just found one reason, why the second clickable span is not a good solution :( it turns the second part into a link (blue), which is not what i wanted. Sorry. So can't award you the points in that case.

Answer (score 0):

For all who interessted to do that with [EmojisTextView](https://github.com/sharakova/EmojiTextView/blob/master/src/jp/sharakova/android/emoji/EmojiTextView.java) from what @babay said in the fist answer i make some chages like that:

```
public class EmojiconTextView extends TextView {
private int mEmojiconSize;
private int mTextStart = 0;
private int mTextLength = -1;

boolean dontConsumeNonUrlClicks = true;
boolean linkHit;

public EmojiconTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

public EmojiconTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public EmojiconTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs == null) {
        mEmojiconSize = (int) getTextSize();
    } else {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Emojicon);
        mEmojiconSize = (int) a.getDimension(R.styleable.Emojicon_emojiconSize, getTextSize());
        mTextStart = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Emojicon_emojiconTextStart, 0);
        mTextLength = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Emojicon_emojiconTextLength, -1);
        a.recycle();
    }
    setText(getText());
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    EmojiconHandler.addEmojis(getContext(), builder, mEmojiconSize, mTextStart, mTextLength);
    super.setText(builder, type);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    linkHit = false;
    boolean res = super.onTouchEvent(event);

    if (dontConsumeNonUrlClicks)
        return linkHit;
    return res;

}






/**
 * Set the size of emojicon in pixels.
 */
public void setEmojiconSize(int pixels) {
    mEmojiconSize = pixels;
}


public static class LocalLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {
    static LocalLinkMovementMethod sInstance;


    public static LocalLinkMovementMethod getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new LocalLinkMovementMethod();

        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget,
                                Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += widget.getScrollX();
            y += widget.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(
                    off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

            if (link.length != 0) {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    link[0].onClick(widget);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                            buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                            buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                }

                if (widget instanceof EmojiconTextView){
                    ((EmojiconTextView) widget).linkHit = true;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
                Touch.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return Touch.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }
}
```

}

after that you just do the same here:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(EmojiconTextView.LocalLinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place this line in your adapter item parent view `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Answer (score -2):

well,@babay's answer is right,but he seems had forgot something, you should write "TextViewFixTouchConsume" instead of "TextView" in xml, and then it will be work! for example :

```
<com.gongchang.buyer.widget.TextViewFixTouchConsume xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/wx_comment_friendsname"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/comment_bg_with_grey_selector"
android:lineSpacingExtra="1dp"
android:paddingBottom="1dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_third"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_third"
android:paddingTop="1dp"
android:textColor="@color/text_black_2d"
android:textSize="@dimen/content_second" />
```