# Clickable TextView like Twitter app

Tags: android, text, twitter, hyperlink, clickable

I'm trying to make a list view of tweets.
I want the relevent parts of the strings to be clickable just like in the Twitter app.
I tried to linkify the text but than the view is not clickable because that the text is "taking" the clicks. When a user clicks on a spot that does not have a link than the hole view should be clicked and get to "onItemClick".
What is the way to do it or is there a good library that can help with that?

Comment: There's quite a workaround to achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558732/listview-textview-with-linkmovementmethod-makes-list-item-unclickable

Comment: The link you are providing is not exactly what I need, there they only want the text to be clickable from a certain point.  not on any link in the middle of the string.