# clickable span in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, spannablestring

I'm trying to implement a comment like list where you can mention other users in the comments, and then be able to click on that to go to their profile. For example, when posting a comment on reddit you can mention another user with /u/username.

The one problem i'm running into is how to make it so I can click on the text to load that user's profile.

For the comment list I essentially have a custom list of textviews. From googling around I saw that it is possible to be able to click on some text in a textview using a clickable span. However, I haven't been able to get this to work in a list of textviews. Can someone help?

This is the relevant sections of my code:

Clickable span I declared as a member variable:

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
        // ParseUser.getQuery().whereEqualTo(Constants.kQollegeUserPreferredUsernameKey, sta)
        intent.putExtra("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Inside getView:

```
    TextView answer_text_view = answerView.getAnswerTextView();

    String text = answer.getAnswerText();
    if(text.contains("@")) {
        text += " ";
        final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

        List<Integer> start = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = text.indexOf("@");
        while (index >= 0) {
            start.add(index);
            index = text.indexOf("@", index + 1);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<start.size(); i++){
            sb.setSpan(fcs, start.get(i), text.indexOf(" ", start.get(i)), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            sb.setSpan(clickableSpan, start.get(i), text.indexOf(" ", start.get(i)), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

        answer_text_view.setText(sb);
    }
```

Comment: afaik you cannot use the same span in multiple places

Comment: this concept is called [linkify](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html). here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview).

Comment: @RahulTiwari does linkify work to start other activities? I'm not trying to go to a URL, just starting an intent

Comment: you can implement  it as you need.

Comment: so what is not working?

Comment: @RahulTiwari Could you link me to or write an example as to how you would start another activity via an intent using linkify?

Comment: Check example from my first comment

Comment: @RahulTiwari I've looked through the example you linked, but it didn't have anytthing about using linkify to begin a new activity, just to load urls/webpages which is not what I need

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19989677/1529129)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView: TextView with LinkMovementMethod makes list item unclickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558732/listview-textview-with-linkmovementmethod-makes-list-item-unclickable)

Answer (score 1):

I have applied following to the textview where clickable span is present to make it work

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```