# Navigation to other activities by clicking on certain words in text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button

I want to display a text where certain words lead to other activities within the application.
Is there a more convenient way to achieve it other than having a bunch of TextViews along with buttons (with the clickable words and a transparent background) side by side?

Answer (score 0):

Just the bunch of TextViews and their onClick(s) should do, you wouldn't need the Buttons..

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class, that searches for some predefined links in the text such as phone numbers, e-mail addresses and web links and automatically makes them clickable and leading to the corresponding activities when clicked. I think there is a possibility of adding your own pattern to recognize words in the text and bind them to activities you want to be used for those words. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check both of the links

http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/

[handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)