# Format TextView to look like link

Tags: android

I've been using the `android:autoLink` just fine for formatting links and such, but I need to use `android:onClick` so I can't use that in this case.  The reasoning is that I find it too easy to click on a phone number accidentally, so I'm going to intercept the click with a confirmation `Dialog` and then call.

Is there an easy way to still make the phone number in my `TextView` look like a normal clickable link?  I poked around the Android source code, but couldn't find any particular style for me to reference.

Comment: One solution would be to extend ClickableSpan to do your own custom handling of clicking the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html Also check this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413399/open-textview-links-at-another-activity-not-default-browser

Answer (score 14):

This is the shortest solution:

```
final CharSequence text = tv.getText();
final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString( text );
spannableString.setSpan(new URLSpan(""), 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Sadly, the effect of clicking doesn't show up as being clicked on a real url link, but you can overcome it like so:

```
    final CharSequence text = tv.getText();
    final SpannableString notClickedString = new SpannableString(text);
    notClickedString.setSpan(new URLSpan(""), 0, notClickedString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(notClickedString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    final SpannableString clickedString = new SpannableString(notClickedString);
    clickedString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, notClickedString.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                tv.setText(clickedString);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                tv.setText(notClickedString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                v.performClick();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                tv.setText(notClickedString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Another solution is to use Html.fromHtml(...) , where the text inside has links tags ("") .

If you wish for another solution, check [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623872/how-to-show-links-on-textviews-and-be-able-to-handle-them-correctly).

Answer (score 3):

- You can create a colors.xml resource file, what contains colors. Please take a look at [Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/android-color-xml-resource-file)
- If you want to underline your text, then please take a look at this post:
  [Underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout)
- Don't forget to add `android:clickable="true"` or `setClickable(true)` to
  your TextViews to make them clickable!

Answer (score 3):

To underline your TextView's text, you have to do something like:

```
final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

SpannableString string = new SpannableString("This is the uderlined text.");
string.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, string.length(), 0);
text.setText(string);
```

This should work. Let me know about your progress.

Comment: just replace content with string and then only your code will work fine. because content is nothing here.

Answer (score 3):

Linkify is a great class, it hunts for complex patterns like URLs, phone numbers, etc and turns them into URLSpans. Rather than re-write the existing regular expressions I extended the URLSpan class and created a method to upgrade *only* the telephone URLSpans to a custom URLSpan with a confirmation dialog.

**First** my extended URLSpan class, ConfirmSpan:

```
class ConfirmSpan extends URLSpan {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    View mView;

    public ConfirmSpan(URLSpan span) {
        super(span.getURL());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        mView = widget;

        if(dialog == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(widget.getContext());
            mBuilder.setMessage("Do you want to call: " + getURL().substring(4) + "?");
            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    openURL();
                }
            });
            dialog = mBuilder.create();
        }
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void openURL() {
        super.onClick(mView);
    }
}
```

**Next** the method to swap out the different span classes:

```
private void swapSpans(TextView textView) {
    Spannable spannable = (Spannable) textView.getText();
    URLSpan[] spans = textView.getUrls();
    for(URLSpan span : spans) {
        if(span.getURL().toString().startsWith("tel:")) {
            spannable.setSpan(new ConfirmSpan(span), spannable.getSpanStart(span), spannable.getSpanEnd(span), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spannable.removeSpan(span);
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally** all you need to do is create a TextView with the autoLink attribute:

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

And remember to call the `swapSpans()` method. Understand that I wrote this for fun, there may be other methods of doing this but I am unaware of them at the moment. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this looks very nice!  I will try to implement it soon and see how it goes. :)

Answer (score 1):

With kotlin extension function (if you don't need the click effect as on a real link)

```
fun TextView.hyperlinkStyle() {
    setText(
        SpannableString(text).apply {
            setSpan(
                URLSpan(""),
                0,
                length,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        },
        TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE
    )
}
```

How to use

```
yourTextView.hyperlinkStyle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a better answer.This is what i did.

```
     final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Click here to verify Benificiary");
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {

            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan,0,ss.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setHighlightColor(Color.BLUE);
```

---

You go anywhere you like when user clicks on the link through onclick method of ClickableSpan

Answer (score 0):

Simply underline it:

```
val myText = "Text to be underlined"
textView.text = Html.fromHtml("<u>$myText</u>")
```

or with kotlin extensions:

```
fun TextView.underline() {
    text = Html.fromHtml("<u>${text}</u>")
}
```

usage:

```
textView.text = myText
textView.underline()
```

More ways to style text in android here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568