# Converting a SpannableString to a ClickableSpan

Tags: android, linkify, spannablestring

I am trying to make clickable links in text strings that launch an activity when clicked. I have used Linkify() to detect links in my text. This function is capable of adding links to text, but only web URLs. I need to turn my output into a ClickableSpan so that I can implement [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025770/android-launch-activity-from-clickable-text/4026303#4026303).

How do I get Linkify()'s identified links to become ClickableSpans which direct to an activity?

Below is the code I have used in Linkify:

```
// Linkify parameters
final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[^]]*]"); // defines the fact that links are bound by [square brackets]
final String scheme = "http://"; // TODO: Currently this is just a blank link
Linkify.addLinks(linkText, pattern, scheme);
```

Comment: I did something similar to this: [Format TextView to look like link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11820526/1267661). If you combine the technique in your link with my `swapSpans()` method you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to achieve, it's probably simpler to just override the `startActivity()` method in your `Activity` and intercept the `ACTION_VIEW` intents with the URLs in your text. Something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
            // launch our other activity instead
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
            ourIntent.setData(intent.getData());
            super.startActivity(ourIntent);

            // we're done!
            return;
        }

        // else, normal handling by the framework
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }

    // the rest of your activity code

}
```

For reference, [here's the source code for URLSpan](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/style/URLSpan.java) which will trigger the `startActivity()` method above.

Comment: I've been looking at this for days now, and I simply can't work out what you're suggesting... Am I supposed to have this as a separate class that is never called, but which waits for a URL to be clicked on?

Comment: As I understand it, I need to put this code at the start of my program, and have it wait for a URL to be clicked. My activity, when it is launched, takes a few variables. These are not available to this piece of code at the beginning of my program... or are they?

Comment: The `startActivity()` method override above should be added to your `Activity` class (the one which displays the text that has been processed by `Linkify()`).

Comment: When you say _"My activity, when it is launched, takes a few variables"_ - are the variables passed in as extras in an `Intent`? If so, they should be accessible as usual to this `startActivity()` method by calling `getIntent()`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get Linkify()'s identified links to become ClickableSpans which direct to an activity?

After your call to `addLinks()`, call `getText()` to retrieve the `Spanned` object from the `TextView`. This object will have a series of `URLSpan` objects, one per matched link -- you can get an array of those through a call to `getSpans()`. You will need to note where each those spans start and end (via `getSpanStart()` and `getSpanEnd()`), remove the `URLSpan`, and replace it with your own spans to do what you want.