# How to make deep link string clickable in android TextView

Tags: android, textview, deep-linking

How do I make a deep link string for example "myapp://product/123" clickable in android TextView. I know there are autoLink options like email, web and phone but there isn't any deeplink option. How do I make it clickable and launch the intent on click of that link?

Comment: what about using `android:autoLink="web"` attribute ?

Comment: Didn't work... Since it's not a weblink

Comment: That means you are trying to make some specific word clickable in `TextView` ?

Comment: No. I was trying to make a deeplink string clickable

Comment: upon the click I want to make an explicit intent and launch it so that I can go to specific activity that is registered with same intent filter and category

Comment: Are you wanting this link to be clickable everywhere, or *only* within the context of a `TextView` inside your own app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do that by using `ClickableSpan`

eg.

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
};
```

See this link [How to set the part of the text view is clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to make code as like below in java file.That can be you can click to any link from textview.

```
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. But that didn't help

Comment: Works only for http/https scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
YourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer.. But that didn't help

Comment: if you added android:autoLink="web" in xml layout, then remove that property and try.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509741/2914140, I wrote similar:

```
val url = "myapp://example.com/some_string"
textView.text = url
textView.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))
}
```

You don't even need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in `AndroidManifest`.

If you have an application, responding to `myapp` scheme and `example.com` host, it will be opened.

To format the `textView` [like a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55484544/2914140) also write:

```
textView.hyperlinkStyle()


private fun TextView.hyperlinkStyle() {
    setText(
        SpannableString(text).apply {
            setSpan(
                URLSpan(""),
                0,
                length,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        },
        TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE
    )
}
```