# Open TextView links at another activity - custom ClickableSpan

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a TextView with links *and* other text. I need to links to be clickable & I need to capture the click and open the link in a webview in my activity. I followed this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11417498/489177). My code looks like this:

**actitivity_main.xml**

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textlinktest"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

And this is the way I invoke it:

```
textLinkTest.setText(Html.fromHtml("Something else <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>"));

textLinkTest.setText(RichTextUtils.replaceAll(
            (Spanned) textLinkTest.getText(),
            URLSpan.class,
            new URLSpanConverter()));
```

**The links show up fine, but they are not clickable! The onclick in my customeclickablespan never gets called.**  I tried toggling android:linksClickable & also tried different values for android:autoLink. But the links remain unclickable. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
textLinkTest.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

before

```
textLinkTest.setText(RichTextUtils.replaceAll((Spanned) textLinkTest.getText(), URLSpan.class, new URLSpanConverter()));
```