# ActivityNotFoundException when clicking TextView's internal deep link to other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking

I have application which has activity that shows product pages with long text descriptions in a TextView. In the description text I have links to other products that opens new instance of the same activity displaying the product. I am getting bug reports that I am unable to reproduce.

TextView has links like this:

```
<a href=\"android-app://com.package.name/http/appname/category/item/\">item</a>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml for the same activity where TextView is I have intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://appname/*/*/" -->
  <data
    android:host="appname"
    android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/"
    android:scheme="http" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I set the TextView text like this:

```
tx.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(id)));
tx.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This works fine on all my test devices, however I am getting several bug reports in Developer Console:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
  { act=android.intent.action.VIEW 
    dat=android-app://com.package.name/http/appname/categoryname/itemname/ (has extras) }
  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
  ...
```

Any ideas what could be causing the bugs?

Comment: Where is the intent code that opens another activity to show other products from the description link? it looks like your intent is expecting extras

Comment: There is no "intent code", the TextView handles links automatically.

Comment: This might help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413399/open-textview-links-at-another-activity-not-default-browser

Comment: These Links might help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413399/open-textview-links-at-another-activity-not-default-browser

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app