# How to intercept click on link in TextView?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have TextView and it contain HTML with  tags. I need to intercept user's clicks on this links, take value of "href" parameter, check it and open my activity if it local link or open browser if it link to another site.

I've try to search and find [that](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/), but I can't understand how to use it in my case.

Please, help.

Comment: I can't answer your question for doing this in a TextView.  It seems like a WebView would suit your purpose.

Comment: And if you finally use the WebView, remember, JavaScript is disabled by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handle textview link click in my android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452944/1799219

All it's really doing is passing the link to your own activity (as links are normally passed to other activities) and then you extract the URL.