# Open settings from TextView link

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to link, one to open downloads, and other to open network settings. My own link I am handling by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452944/312161

I try to do same thing for internet settings:

```
<a href="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS">internet connection.</a>
```

But I get error:

```
03-20 14:01:17.265: E/AndroidRuntime(21051): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS (has extras) }
```

Maybe someone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not directly possible. Hyperlinks in `TextView` will only do an `ACTION_VIEW` operation on the supplied URL. There is no `ACTION_VIEW` to open a settings screen.

It is unclear to me why you are doing this from a hyperlink in a `TextView` in the first place, versus using a normal command UI construct, such as an action bar item or a `Button`.

Be that as it may, you are welcome to create a hyperlink that leads to one of your own activities, that in turn launches the settings screen.

Comment: I don't have enough space for two buttons, also this functions is unnecessary, but add a bit comfortable. Is any place where I can see all default `ACTION_VIEW` intents?

Comment: @neworld: "Is any place where I can see all default ACTION_VIEW intents?" -- not really.

Comment: how do you know there is no ACTION_VIEW for opening settings?

Comment: @neworld: First, because the Settings app can and is modified by device manufacturers, and so there are no guarantees about *any* `Intent` being able to work (even `android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS`). Second, I read the AOSP Settings app's manifest file: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml