# How to start new activity by clicking Link in TextView

Tags: textview, uri, linkify

I have ViewActivity with TextView in wich i set Spanned Text from resource txt file.

ViewActivity:

```
    Spanned textSP = android.text.Html.fromHtml(text);
    tvtv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtv);
    tvtv.setText(textSP);
    Linkify.addLinks(tvtv, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

I create link with some ID information as it is written in this article [handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app).
It is necessary that by clicking on the link, download SecondAcitvity (with other TextView) of my application (not the browser).

SecondActivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statya);        
    //пытаемся перейти со ссылки
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    String data2 = data.getLastPathSegment();
    TextView tvStatya = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStatya);
    tvStatya.setText(data2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

put an onClick in your xml like this

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="clickFunction"/>
```

Then in your java

```
public void clickFunction(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work =( i think i sholud create custom linkMovement metod...but how??

Comment: 08-08 13:38:12.469: E/AndroidRuntime(17185): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=women consultation://statya/122 (has extras) }
08-08 13:38:12.469: E/AndroidRuntime(17185):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
08-08 13:38:12.469: E/AndroidRuntime(17185):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)

Comment: is the second activity definitely in the manifest? and have you set up the second activity to handle the extras that you are adding to the intent ?