# Clickable URL in EditText Android

Tags: android, url, android-edittext, clickable, linkify

I have a note editor. I want to be able to paste link in the EditText and make it clickable, but I still want to have the cut/copy/paste menu on long pressing and also I want the link to be opened only if it is clicked, not if I click anywhere else in the EditText. I want to be free to edit the note even if I have links in it. I searched for an answer but didn't understand what to do. Should I use the Linkify class with one of it's add links methods? Please give me an example. I have to complete this task until friday..

Answer (score 0):

Add the autolink property to the EditText: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink)

```
android:autoLink="true"
```

Comment: Using this I'm unable to edit the text. I just click anywhere in the edittext and the browsers start.

Comment: You may have to need the LinkMovementMethod (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.html)  see some examples of usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16644228/684582

Comment: But I still need the long click listener menu for cut/copy/paste