# How to link a part of TextView to an Activity

Tags: android, xamarin.android

So I have a TextView with some text as follows

some text....some text....some text....some text....some text....some text....some text....some text......**href.link**......some other text.....some other text......some other text.....some other text....some other text...

I just want the link part of the text to start another activity when clicked. I am trying to do this in Xamarin, so far I have done the following:

```
TextView1.SetText(Html.FromHtml("<span>some text...<a href='example://'></a>...some other text </span>"
```

In my target activity:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
     DataScheme = "example",
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
```

which I am guessing is equivlent to:

```
<intent-filter>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<data android:scheme="example" />  
</intent-filter>
```

Not sure what to set as the scheme here.

Comment: better keep two textViews very near to achive your target

Comment: You can use html formatting with Html.fromHtml()

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084 link may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently I have to add this to the code (in question) to make it work -

```
TextView1.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing a similar thing in Xamarin. I have a `TextView` called `lblCreateNewAccount` in my Layout. In the `OnCreate` method of the activity, I am doing this:

```
TextView lbl = this.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lblCreateNewAccount);
lbl.TextFormatted = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml ("<u>Create New Account</u>");
lbl.SetTextColor (Color.ParseColor ("#ffffff"));
Typeface face = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (this.Assets, "fonts/OpenSansRegular.ttf");
lbl.SetTypeface (face, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
lbl.Click += lblCreateNewAccount_Clicked;
```

Here is the simplified `lblCreateNewAccount_Clicked` method for you:

```
void lblCreateNewAccount_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartActivity (typeof(NewAccountActivity));
}
```

Basically the concept is to format the `TextView` as an `href` and then implement the `Click` event to navigate to the next activity. Not sure if this is the best and most elegant way but it works for me.

By the way, you will have to use three `TextView` controls in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the whole text is too long to keep them in one line. So keeping three TextViews is not gonna help. Its like the link comes up somewhere in the middle of a paragraph