# Activity to listen to Intent ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open a custom activity in setMovementMethod below.

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHelp);
tx.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.help)));
tx.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I have the html defined with links  which when clicked/pressed, i want my activity to open displaying an image(depending on the clicked link)

I have looked at this thread [handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app][1]) and tried to follow the answer used.
Here my activity in manifest defined to listen to intent action.View.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.metermanager.ImagesActivity"                    
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="com.example.metermanager" />  
    </intent-filter>
```

Here is the activity code.

```
package com.example.metermanager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ImagesActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.images);

        String text= getIntent().getDataString();
        Log.e("link", text);

    }
}
```

But clicking the link causes the error below yet the activity for the intent is defined.

```
 11-19 03:17:04.827: E/InputEventReceiver(1409): Exception dispatching input event.
 11-19 03:17:04.827: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=here (has extras) }
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7713)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 11-19 03:17:04.867: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1409):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-19 03:17:04.867:
```

Any reasons why it is not working?

Ronald

Comment: can you please post html text ?

Comment: I have added it as an edit.
   
       
         
  
  Steps(not in  linear order):<br>
  1: Add Meters <a href="here"> Meters </a>  <br>
  
 

  
  
    ]]>
    </string>

Comment: <string name="help">
    <![CDATA[   
  
  Steps(not in  linear order):<br>
  1: Add Meters <a href="here"> Meters </a>  <br>
  
 

  
  
    ]]>
    </string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your URL to link to the activity.

Your data schema declaration seems to be wrong.

Try

`<data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.example.metermanager" />`

instead of

`<data android:scheme="com.example.metermanager" />`

In addition your links should not be

`<a href="here">`

but

`<a href="content://com.example.metermanager/some_specific_data">`

Comment: I understood, that you have links in html you want to open if pressing any of these links. Post such a link, so we can see the format of your links. If you define intent filters, they must match to the link format. We have to know the link format to help you.

Comment: I am opening links. I want to start an activity depending on the string returned..display an image...

Comment: If your link is "here" I edited my answer. Change your links to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

help text must be like below then its match to ImagesActivity intent filter :

```
<string name="help">&lt;a href="com.example.metermanager://ImagesActivity">Start ImagesActivity&lt;/a></string>
```