# How to linkify a part of the message in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, string, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to make part of the Dialog message a link? And assign a click listener to that part?

Let's say I have a dialog like this:

```
String message = "Hello, click here for more info";
String messageClickable = "click here";

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
    .show();
```

How can I make the `messageClickable` part clickable? I researched the class `Linkify` but I could only find method `addLinks` that works with actual links or phone numbers etc.

Comment: You may use Spannable as given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5681946/991085

Comment: @GiruBhai that would work for `TextView`, but how would I use that with `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I ended up using is below:

```
private void showDialogWithClickableMessage() {

    String message = "Hello, click here for more info";
    String messageClickable = "click here";

    SpannableString messageSpannable = new SpannableString(message);

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            // do something
        }
    };

    messageSpannable.setSpan(clickableSpan, message.indexOf(messageClickable), message.indexOf(messageClickable) + messageClickable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(messageSpannable)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_action_ok, null)
            .show();

    ((TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

}
```

Comment: setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())  is one of the important parts in this solution