# Opening the facebook app through a textview?

Tags: android

By clicking on the URL that is in `TextView`, I would direct redirect to the Facebook application.

The following is a code excerpt that I have to leave the textview clicked

```
// Checking for null feed url
    if (item.getUrl() != null) {
        url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

        // Making url clickable
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

#### Example Image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipy3D.png]

When you click the `TextView` it opens the app chooser dialog to complete the action. I would like it to directly open Facebook

Comment: What do you want to do? 
Open facebook normaly or open a concrete thing of facebook like post a message or a concrete post etc..
Is important to answer you

Comment: I like it when the User click the textview open facebook and not the choice window.

Comment: @William you are going against the preferred Android user experience. Android users expect the flexibility that you are trying to take away. Also - what if the Facebook app is not installed? Does the TextView click do nothing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [handle textview link click in my android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)

Comment: @Phil You're right, but could put any condition to make click only if you have installed the Facebook app.

Comment: There is no way I can draw a direct link to the facebook app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written your application this is ***not possible***

Deep Linking through HREF is not yet able to not use the App chooser.

This is a feature scheduled for release in [Android M](https://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html).

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_name" android:autoVerify="true">
   //...categories etc
</intent-filter>
```

More info [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/28/io-2015-android-m-will-support-app-deep-linking-without-that-annoying-selector-prompt/)

---

### BUT

You can still deep link directly between your app and the Facebook app. You can do it in multiple ways.

The Facebook API has extensive documentation on this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android