# How to make a part of a text clickable (appcelerator, android)

Tags: android, appcelerator, clickablespan

I am trying to achieve a functionality where user can click a part of a text such as the username or a hashtag in a string which is used by most social apps.
There doesn't seem to be a way as of now.
Any help will be most appreciated.
Ti SDK 5.2.2
Android

Comment: Your problem is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app) Apart from [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3452944/805105) also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16644228/805105).

Comment: you can use rich text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an [AttributedString](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AttributedString). It allows you to display "html" like text. There is an easy to use module: https://github.com/FokkeZB/ti-html2as where you can set HTML text and it will convert it to an AttributedString.

So you would use a regular expression to convert you clickable elements (e.g. `#element` -> `<a href="#element">#element</a>`) and check for the click response