# Clickable link handler in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, textview

Similar to this SO question, I'm trying to display clickable links in a TextView: [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

But I don't just want the link to open a website. I want to handle the click event myself and, say, launch an activity. Here is what I have so far:

```
myTextView.movementMethod = object: LinkMovementMethod() {
    override fun onTouchEvent(widget: TextView?, buffer: Spannable?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        doTheThing()

        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event)
    }
}
```

And on my TextView:

```
android:text="Foo <a href="bar">Bar</a>"
```

As expected, "Bar" is underlined in blue, but the onTouchEvent is tripped whenever I click on the whole TextView, including on Foo. I only want it to fire when I tap "Bar" because that's what's underlined. Also, what if I had multiple links in the text? How would I get each one to respond differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string in to parts: Before link text, link text, after link text:

`<string name="part_1">Here is a </string>
    <string name="link_text">link</string>
    <string name="part_2"> for you to tap</string>`

Then use a `SpannableStringBuilder` to assemble the parts, and when you add the link text, set a `ClickableSpan` with the appropriate link handler on the span from the end of part 1 string to the end of the part 1 + link string:

`SpannableStringBuilder  builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(getString(R.string.part_1));
    int spanStart = builder.length();
    builder.append(getString(R.string.link_text));
    int spanEnd = builder.length();
    builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            // Do my thang
        }
    }, spanStart, spanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.append(getString(R.string.part_2));
    textView.setText(builder);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`